# MVC3 - @readonly="readonly" not coming through on a textareafor under IE8. Works fine in other browsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, internet-explorer-8, readonly

So I'm generating a textarea element using MVC3. I generate my element with the following mark-up:

```
<%=Html.TextAreaFor(model=> model.Description, new { value=Model.Description, @class="readonlyDescription", placeholder = "No " + Model.DescriptionLabel.ToLower() + " provided", @readonly = "readonly", rows = 1, cols = 30}) %>
```

When generated under Google Chrome I see:

```
<textarea class="readonlyDescription" cols="30" id="Description" name="Description" placeholder="No description provided" readonly="readonly" rows="1" value=""></textarea>
```

When generated under IE9 I see:

```
<textarea name="Description" class="readonlyDescription" id="Description" rows="1" cols="30" readOnly="readonly" value="" placeholder="No description provided">
```

When generated under IE8 I see:

```
<textarea name="Description" class="readonlyDescription placeholder" id="Description" rows="1" cols="30" readOnly="" value="" placeholder="No description provided" jQuery172027049094255782585="250">
```

Note that my readonly attribute has gone missing. Where did it go?

I've also tried using @readonly = "true" but did not see any differing effects.

EDIT: I suspect it IS coming across, but IE8 is just treating the existance of 'readonly' as enough for it to be enabled. Then, it handles readonly differently than IE9. So, I'm using disabled instead of readonly with the additional CSS of making the background transparent (as to look readonly and not disabled)

Comment: Disabled comes across fine, but in modern browsers it modifies the background color, etc.. and generally doesn't give the look I am hoping for. I can definitely override the CSS and use disabled, but just wondering what happened to my readonly.

Comment: why dont you try to write html insted of using razor helpers? some times it solves lot of problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

readonly only has one value, and that is readonly, so it is valid for the presence of the readonly attribute to be enough to render it readonly.

same for disabled, simply the presence of the attribute is enough

In JS, to enable or make a control editable, you remove those attributes rather than set them to true or false.

[W3Schools has some to say on it](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp)

Comment: Yeah, IE just handles stuff extremely weird. My textarea can take focus/be clicked/lose its placeholder with the 'readonly' attribute in IE. However, in all other modern browsers, the readonly attribute prevents focusing entirely on a textarea. If I mark my textarea as disabled, I can prevent focusing, but IE does not let me change the font color of a disabled element, so I have no way of making it look 'readonly' without javascript.